# Outbound Conference Call using Twilio

Tags: twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am trying to plan out how to place outbound conference calls using twilio. On the frontend I am using Twilio.client and using the .connect() to place the call. I was wondering how I could place an outbound call and put that number into a conference call. Then I can enter another number on the web app and place another outbound call, placing the two numbers in the same conference call.

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. [What is your answerable programming question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) `I was wondering how I could place an outbound call and…` What happened to make that a thing of the past?

Comment: I assume the question is: How can I perform an outbound call in Twilio but creating a voice conference instead of normal two-party call?